# Using hover function on hr element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav, underline

I want to use an hr element as an underline for a navigation bar, but I am having trouble using jquery to move the positioning of the hr. It seems to be fixed to the top of the webpage, when I would like it underneath, so that I can hover over different links and the hr element will slide over to that link. Any ideas?

html:

```js
    $('#tt').hover(function(){
        console.log("hi");
      $('hr').css("margin-left: 50%");
    
    })
```

```css
    nav{
      font-size: 1.85em;
    
    }
    
    nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#000;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 1vh;
    }
    
    #one{
      margin-left: 2vw;
    }
    
    .floatright{
      float:right;
      padding-right: 3vw;
    }
    .floatright a{
        margin-left: 4vw;
    }
    
    
    hr {
      height: .25rem;
      width: 9.5%;
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 1.3vw;
      background: tomato;
      border: none;
      transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      top: 6vh;
    }
    
    a:hover ~ hr{
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            <nav>
              <a id="one" href="#">name</a>
              <div class="floatright">
                <a id="tt" href="#">Link One</a>
                <a href="#">Link Two</a>
                <a href="#">Link Three</a>
                <a href="#">Link Four</a>
                </div>
                <hr />
    
              </nav>
</div>
```

codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwzYje

Comment: do you must use `hr`?

Comment: what other alternatives are there?

Comment: You should use `.css()` like `.css("margin-left", "50%")` or `.css({"margin-left": "50%"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Md. Salahuddin - the simplest thing would be to add some `:hover` styling to your elements, either underline or a border depending on where you want the line. Md. Saladahuddin has provided examples for underlining via CSS stylesheets and jquery.

Personally I prefer using `border-bottom` as this lets you decide the color and thickness, as well as using `padding-bottom` to determine how far the line is from the text. I add a white border (or whatever color the background is) so that other elements aren't pushed down you hover.

```
nav a {
    border-bottom: 3px white solid;
}

nav a:hover {
   border-bottom: 3px tomato solid;  
}
```

---

**Or, if you want the animation to move across the screen** then this is a solution using jquery and a div (rather than a `hr`). This works best on fullscreen, you'd need to add a responsive check for smaller screens (i.e. use a sidenav or similar on mobiles).

```js
$(".underline-nav").css("width", $("#one").width());
$(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $("#one").css("margin-left"));

$('nav a').hover(function(){
  
    $(".underline-nav").css("width", $(this).width());
    $(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $(this).css("margin-left"));

    var position = $(this).position();
    $(".underline-nav").css("left", position.left);


})
```

```css
.underline-nav {
  background: red;
  height: .25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.65em;
  transition:all ease 0.3s;

}
nav{
  font-size: 1.85em;

}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}

#one{
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.floatright{
  float:right;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}
.floatright a{
    margin-left: 4vw;
}

a:hover ~ hr{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <nav>
          <a id="one" href="#">name</a>
          <div class="floatright">
            <a id="tt" href="#">Link One</a>
            <a href="#">Link Two</a>
            <a href="#">Link Three</a>
            <a href="#">Link Four</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="underline-nav">
            </div>

          </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple css to do it. just remove your hr tag, related css and add this css

```
nav a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQPqmw

If you really want to do it using jquery you can do like this: Here hover method uses two methods for both mouseenter and mouseleaves events.

```
$('nav a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
}, function() {
   $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxVydw